# How to set the storePassword in signingConfig of app/build.gradle if it contains $ in the keystore password

Tags: android, mobile-development

How to set the storePassword in app/build.gradle if it contains $ in the keystore password.

For say test$app.

Howcan i set this in my Signing config of app level build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try escaping this character:

`"test\$app"`